# Git Files 'not found' on 'git clone'

Tags: git, github, raspberry-pi, clone

I'm trying to clone from a private git repo onto my raspberry pi but run into an issue when trying to clone where the files that are in the repo are known (according to the output) but the files are 'not found'.

[image]

I can clone this repo in my normal terminal on my computer but run into the issue only when trying to clone this repo into my pi when SSH'd to my pi. There doesn't seem to be any explanations for this error specifically documented online.

Comment: just as a check does it work if you were to make your repository public?

Comment: This looks like a botched Git installation. The `git-remote-https` file in the `git-core` directory has been overwritten with a list of files, and instead of being an executable that can run, it's being treated as a shell script. Re-install Git.